# String pattern delimiter

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string first = "2-18;1-4; 5-212; 4-99" ;
Char delimiter = '-';

String pattern = @"\s?(\d+)([-])(\d+)";
```

And I would like to know if there is any way to put the delimiter in the pattern instead of the `([-])` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings):

```
string first = "2-18;1-4; 5-212; 4-99" ;
Char delimiter = '-';

String pattern = $@"\s?(\d+)([{delimiter}])(\d+)";
```

The `$` sign (which has to be in front of the `@`) makes it possible to put a variable (string) in a string by using `{` `}`

**Note:** In older versions of C# however this will not work

In this case you can use [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string.Format(@"\s?(\d+)([{0}])(\d+)", delimiter);
```

This works the same way but uses number placeholders for the parameters after the `,`

---

**[Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx): (Credits to NtFreX)**

Additionally if you are using regex you should escape your character (because they can mean something else in regex).

```
$@"\s?(\d+)([{Regex.Escape( delimiter.ToString() )}])(\d+)";
```

Comment: Nice. Although a reference to "string interpolation" would make this even better.

Comment: @Bathsheba just posted still improving post :) nice touch :)

Comment: Very interesting

Comment: Have made an edit - this is the way the cool cats like to present links. But rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @EpicKip Please add [@NtFrex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44919476/1548895) `Regex.Escape`. This will make your example more flexible.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Good thinking, ill put it there in a minute :)

Answer (score 2):

This is simplest string concatenation. You have several options:

string concatenation:

```
Char delimiter = '-';

String pattern = @"\s?(\d+)([" + delimiter + "])(\d+)";
```

string.Format():

```
Char delimiter = '-';

String pattern = string.Format(@"\s?(\d+)([{0}])(\d+)", delimiter);
```

new style Format (only works with newer C# versions):

```
Char delimiter = '-';

String pattern = $@"\s?(\d+)([{delimiter}])(\d+)";
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionaly I would use [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) to escape the delimiter.

```
$@"\s?(\d+)([{Regex.Escape(delimiter)}])(\d+)";
```

For example if the delimiter is `.` it needs to be changed into `\.` because `.` is a special regex character which matches any character. The same goas for other characters.

Comment: Used this in my answer, thanks :), hope you don't mind (gave credit of course)

Comment: @EpicKip No problem. This site is for good answers so perfect.

Comment: Inside of character classes, the dot `.` doesn't need escaping. Hyphen `-` doesn't need escaping so long as it's the first, last (or only) character in the class. They'll still be parsed fine if you unnecessarily escape them so in this case it's a good thing since the pattern is coming from user input. But keep that in mind for a "nornal" regex because escaping too much can lead to readability issues.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 ah I didn't know that. Thanks for the info